# Spring boot - Jackson date format

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I have set the date format to `spring.jackson.date-format=dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`in application.properties but jackson is formatting it as `2017-08-19T10:08:38`. 
Is something wrong with the format i have mentioned in the properties or by default it supports only one format?

Comment: Could you share some code , How is the serializer class defined and what is the input string from frontend ?

Comment: I have not defined any serializer myself. I am trying using the inbuilt feature

Comment: I mean share some code and what is the json passed from front end and what is the model ?

Comment: Are you creating the `ObjectMapper` bean yourself?

Comment: No I am not creating an object mapper by my data uses java.time api

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot jackson date format works fine with below example:

**Application Class**:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @RestController
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

        @PostMapping("/format")
        public Model postModel(@RequestBody Model model){
            System.out.println("Model model"+model.toString());             
            return model;

        }




        protected static class Model{

            private Date date;

            public Date getDate() {
                return date;
            }

            public void setDate(Date date) {
                this.date = date;
            }

            public Model(Date date) {
                super();
                this.date = date;
            }

            public Model() {
                super();

            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Model [date=" + date + "]";
            }   


        }
    }
```

**application.properties**:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

**Input** :

```
{

    "date": "10-12-2016 10:00:00"
}
```

**Output** :

```
{

    "date": "10-12-2016 10:00:00"
}
```